# FullCalendar basic setup doesn't create slots in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working with FullCalendar 2.4.0 and right now I have strange problem. Here's my calendarOpt:

```
var calendarOpt = {
  header: {
    left: 'prev today next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month agendaWeek',
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  editable: false,
  monthNames: ['Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec','Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień'],
  monthNamesShort: ['sty','lut','mar','kwi','maj','cze','lip','sie','wrz','paź','lis','gru'],
  dayNames: ['Niedziela','Poniedziałek','Wtorek','Środa','Czwartek','Piątek','Sobota'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Nie','Pon','Wt','Śr','Czw','Pt','Sob'],
  firstDay: 1,
  allDayDefault: false,
  allDaySlot: false,
  slotDuration: '0:15:00',
  buttonText: {
    today: 'aktualny',
    month: 'Miesiąc',
    week: 'Tydzień',
    day: 'Dzień'
  },
  axisFormat: 'H:mm',
  timeFormat: 'H:mm',
  columnFormat: {
    month: 'dddd',
    week: 'dddd DD.MM',
    day: 'dddd DD.MM'
  },
  titleFormat: {
    month: 'MMMM YYYY',
    week: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    day: 'dddd, DD.MM.YYYY'
  },
  aspectRatio: 0.2,
  slotEventOverlap : false
};
```

Then, in HTML I have

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

and from the console (I'm testing right now) I go

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(calendarOpt)
```

Unfortunately, I got 'empty table", with only one table line (tr), without slots or hours.

[image: View of the calendar after initializing]

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it's still bugging me, but I've moved to older version (1.6.7) and everything is working fine. An answer would be nice though ;)